# Ошибка при запуске grunt nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webkit, grunt

Помогите, плз, разобраться в проблеме. Написал приложение на nw.js, пытаюсь собрать его с помощью grunt + node-webkit, однако при запуске команды сборки возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что за ошибка я могу понять, я не могу понять, как ее исправить. Что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок нашел ответ. Смысл в том, что если использовать nw.js, то нужен соответствующий билдер - grunt-nw-builder. Вот ссылка: https://github.com/nwjs/grunt-nw-builder
Собственно внутри все описано. От себя добавлю лишь то, что у билдера большое количество различных настроек, при этом он откровенно прост и для небольших приложений достаточно указать лишь 2 - 3 пункта из всего списка этих настроек.